# System monitor in corner of Desktop whenever I boot into Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, system-monitor

Every time I boot into Ubuntu, I get this small system monitor like window and if I click outside of the box it will be removed, but I still want to know what is causing this.

[image: Desktop Capture]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it is a conky window. Conky is a system monitor for X Windows that displays statistics about your system and can be configured in the `.conkyrc` file that is in your home directory. If your intention is removing it you should be able to by running:

```
sudo apt-get purge conky*
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I could remove it easily with a command 
'sudo apt autoremove conky'